# How to disable the hover effect of Vuetify data tables?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

The data tables from Vuetify have a hover effect by default. I found this CSS class applied when I check for the table row,

```
.theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

So it seems that this adds the background color to the table row. But when I add this scoped CSS to the Vuetify component,

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :disable-sort="true"
    hide-default-footer
    :item-key="itemKey"
  >
    <template v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)" :slot="slot" slot-scope="scope">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseDataTable",
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    itemKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "id"
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.theme--light.v-data-table
  tbody
  tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content) {
  background: #fff;
}
</style>
```

It does literally nothing with the new CSS I've added. Even when I add `!important` after the background. Can someone tell me why the new CSS rules don't work or even don't get applied? Because I can't even see them in the console.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is my solution

```
<style lang="scss">  
  tbody {
     tr:hover {
        background-color: transparent !important;
     }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Works perfectly on latest vuetify - cheers

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to use the deep selectors:

```
<style scoped>
.v-data-table
  /deep/
  tbody
  /deep/
  tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content) {
  background: #ffffff !important;
}
</style>
```

Now the styling gets applied to all the Data Tables. If someone has any further explanation feel free to answer this question.

Comment: Are you able to provide a hosted example of your code?  Also note that /deep/ is being deprecated so use ::v-deep instead.

Comment: @FrankFurter for some reason `::v-deep` and `>>>` are not working but `/deep/` does could you explain to me why? I can try to make a CodeSandBox

Comment: it may be dependent on the Sass processor library you're using, I believe sass and dart-sass have deprecated `>>>` and `/deep/`.  See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913

Comment: This is also how I fixed it, but using `::v-deep` with `sass` (dart-sass). You could write global CSS and not have to use the deep selector, but if you want to override the hover styles when used in a specific component this is the way to do it. In order to make it work with .theme--dark as well, I'd recommend setting `background: inherit` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Vue CLI then you can modify this using [SASS/SCSS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) too.

```
$material-light: (
  'table': (
    'active': map-get($grey, 'lighten-4'),
    'hover': transparent, // <<<<<<<<< THIS HERE <<<<<<<<<
    'group': map-get($grey, 'lighten-4')
  )
);
```

This overrides Vuetify's table hover styles for example ..
What's useful are some additional variables which you can find on the API page for the specific component you want to modify. An example for data-table: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#sass-variables

Answer (score 2):

For Vuetify 1.5 use:

```
.v-table tr:hover:not(.v-table__expanded__content) {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
.v-data-table >>> tr:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this giving the table an id="mytable" and:

```
<style scoped>
#mytable >>> tr:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
</style>
```